pH probe equation derivation
This is a bit of a niche question, but I am struggling to find a good answer just by Googling around. I've been reading recently into the function of pH probes and ion-selective electrodes in general.
For most ion-selective electrodes, I have (I believe) a good understanding of how you can derive an equation from thermodynamic principles that describes how the potential difference across the ion-selective membrane depends on the relative concentrations of the ion on either side of the membrane. Since the ion of interest can move freely between the two solutions of interest, it follows that at equilibrium, the electrochemical potential of that ion must be the same on either side. From setting the two electrochemical potentials equal to each other, you can derive the typical relationship you see for an ion-selective electrode.
The one I see quoted for pH electrodes, like on this page and in Oxford Chemistry's Electrode Potentials primer, is of a similar form, but I am unsure how you can derive it because I don't see why the electrochemical potential of H+ must be balanced at equilibrium in a glass membrane if H+ does not actually cross the membrane. I think after reading and googling around, I have a good understanding of conceptually why the glass membrane works; as detailed in this post, on each side of the glass, H+ selectively crosses a ~10nm hydrated gel layer, creating a potential difference across this hydrated gel layer. Na+ ions in the dry glass then move if the potential difference on each side of the glass is not the same, resulting in a net current that can be measured by a voltmeter. Conceptually, it makes sense to me why an imbalance in the potential difference across each gel layer would make a measurable voltage. I just don't understand how this equation is derived if no H+ ions cross the membrane. Maybe I am missing something and there is a reason why the H+ electrochemical potential should be the same on either side of the membrane, mediated by the Na+ ions that can migrate freely throughout the entire system, but I would really like to see a nice mathematical proof why it should be the case.
Thank you!

Good post, but can you search in the direction of membrane potentials and Nernst equation?

A potential develops across the membrane because of the difference in [H+]  There is slight ion transfer of Na+ and K+ that must be minimized by a high impedence volt meter ar a bridge method of measurement. it is explained here: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Analytical_Sciences_Digital_Library/Courseware/Analytical_Electrochemistry%3A_Potentiometry/05_pH_Electrodes

@jimchmst The way that the potential develops makes sense to me conceptually, I just don't understand how it leads to the equation I see for pH probes. If no H+ crosses the membrane, why must the electrochemical potential of it be the same on either side?
